What value will be set for the following request parameter?
I am learning Spring mvc framework. This is some code snippet from the view part.
<a href="/main?logout">Log out</a>

In my understanding, when I click this link, I will send a HTTP GET request to the path (/main) in the server with the request parameter logout, right?
(let's say there is a corresponding controller to deal with GET Request)
I use a string to catch the value of logout in the controller, and I found its not null after clicking.
then, what value it will be? Is it some default value if the request parameter is not given in  the key=value format like logout?

Yes when you click this link, It will send a HTTP GET request to the path (/main) in the server with the request parameter logout.
Since no value is assigned to logout when clicking "/main?logout">Log out,your spring mvc controller with get request call will have default value of logout as empty string (i.e "") , when it is read using @RequestParam.
Example: In below code it will print output as Logout parameter value is empty because if block is true as logout string is empty.
@GetMapping("/main")
public String handlingLogout(@RequestParam(value = "logout", required = false) String logout) {
 if (logout.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println("Logout parameter value is empty" + logout);
 }
return "main";
}

output :
Logout parameter value is empty

Thanks for the asking. Also, I checked by myself, like you said, its a empty string. So the default value based on the data type is decided by Spring MVC? I assume?
